# How to change nodejs CLI version on Cpanel/Whm

Tags: node.js, cpanel

On setup nodejs app in the cpanel menu, there are so many version choice.
[image]

But when I login using ssh, the shown version is  `v8.17.0`. How to change to 12 or later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create nodejs application on your cpanel then the NPM binary executable will be created on `/home/yourcpanelusername/nodevenv/yourprojectname/12/bin/`. So just use it, example:

```
~/nodevenv/yourprojectname/12/bin/npm install
```

or if using node:

```
~/nodevenv/yourprojectname/12/bin/node index.js
```